# Access text in dynamic script with Ember using Protractor

Tags: ember.js, protractor

How can I access the text "All changes saved" in the dynamically created Ember script below? I use Protractor to create functional test.

```
<div class="is-muted">
      <script id="metamorph-191-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-191-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script> 
      All changes saved 
      <script id="metamorph-191-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue earlier and solved it in a rather unelegant manner but it does the job, try the following:

```
//$$('#metamorph-191-start') will select all the elements on your page with ID metamorph-191-start
//.get(1) will get the second element that passes this requirement aka the script with your text 'all changes saved' in it.
//the .getText().then(function(foo)... gets the text from the element and resolves the promise around it.
$$('#metamorph-191-start').get(1).getText().then(function(foo){
    console.log(foo);
});
```

I said this was unelegant since it is quite the *bad practice* to use the same ID more than once on a single HTML page.